# Python SyntaxError when running in Windows prompt

Tags: python, syntax-error, runtime-error, command-prompt

When trying to run Python Idle in Windows command prompt, I got the following error:
**File "C:\Users\etc[FileName]", line 1
Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf[xxxx], Oct 5 2020, 15:23:07) [MSC v.1927 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
^**
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Please don't post answers in the question. Post it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I was going to do that, but i was not sure if I would be able to. I will post the answer part as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem:

When I tryed to run python in the Windows command prompt, I executed the file that was saved by the python shell. When that is done, it will always get an error. To get the file running properly, go to File>New file in the python shell, it will open the text editor. In the text editor write your program and save the file .py. Then, in the Windows prompt go to the file directory and type python [the name of your file].py.